# Subquery in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have two collections in MongoDB, Playlists and Songs. It has following data.

Playlists:

```
[{
    "id": "p1",
    "name": "Pop 100",
    "sequence": 1
},
{
    "id": "p2",
    "name": "Classic 100",
    "sequence": 2
}]
```

Songs:

```
[{
    "name": "I Ain't Worried",
    "playlistId": "p1",
    "sequence": 1
},
{
    "name": "Made You Look",
    "playlistId": "p1",
    "sequence": 2
},
{
    "name": "Unholy",
    "playlistId": "p1",
    "sequence": 3
},
{
    "name": "Call Me Maybe",
    "playlistId": "p2",
    "sequence": 1
}]
```

Playlist as well as songs are in sequence. Now in my application, Once playlist is over, it should autoplay next playlist's first audio based on sequence. So when song with sequence 3 in `p1 - sequence 1` playlist ends it should play sequence 1 in playlist `p2 - sequence 2`.

As the first step, I tried aggregation with $group on sequence 1, but I didn't get the desired result. I have achieved it with two queries now.

```
const nextPlaylist = db.playlists.find({sequence: currentPlaylist.sequence + 1})
const nextSong = db.songs.find({sequence: 1, id: nextPlaylist.id})
```

How to get the next song in a single query? Is it also a good idea to do it in a single query instead of two separate queries with hundreds of records?

Answer (score 0):

If the application is getting the songs one at a time, you could get this in one query.  Assuming the application has the sequence number of the current playlist and song, and the current playlist's id, you could use a single aggregation.

- $match in `Playlists` for the current and next sequence number
- $lookup from `Songs` matching Playlists.id with Songs.playlistId, and Songs.sequence is either 1 or the sequence number after the current song
- $unwind the lookup result
- $match for `(Playlists.sequence == current playlist && Songs.sequence == next sequence) || (Playlists.sequence == next playlist && Songs.sequence == 1)`
- $sort by Playlists.sequence ascending
- $limit to 1

What remains will be the next song to play.

Assuming there is are indexes on {sequence: 1} in Playlists and {playlistId:1, sequence:1} in Songs, the query will read 2 playlist documents and 4 song documents.